# Displaying Javascript #document in Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I work with python 2.7 and selenium. I have some troubles to scrap a table generated in Javascript with Selenium. The table code appears when I inspect my webpage but it is never in the source code.

I tried to change the iframe, refresh and many other things. Nothing worked so far with Selenium even if you can see the table or the code in the browser it is never in the page_source we can access in python. It does not seem to be a timing issue no matter how long I wait, it is displayed in the Chrome I control, viewable when inspecting but never when I look at driver.page_source.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd
import time
import json
import re
driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('http://gestion.cnsc.gov.co/WebSetupDocentes/consultarlistas.aspx')
soup=driver.page_source
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(@value,'2')]").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(@value,'158')]").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@type,'submit')]").click()
time.sleep(5)
soup=driver.page_source
```

Any idea is welcome ! I tried switch_frame(), refresh() , I only loaded the network requests in the browser to display only the table. In the end, it is always the same. The table appears in the web browser and in the code I inspect within the browser  but never in page_source where I always get:

```
<html>
        <script>
                function GetFrameSet() {return document.getElementById("frameset");}function GetReportFrame() {return document.getElementById("report");}
        </script><frameset cols="0,*" framespacing="0" frameborder="1" id="frameset">
                <frame src="javascript:''" id="docmap" name="docmap" frameborder="0" class="DocMapFrame" /><frame src="/WebSetupDocentes/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?Mode=true&amp;ReportID=42f77e42746641a58677d148cbb781c5&amp;ControlID=3e3a4ec4b1c9452cbd8ededd9117c3b1&amp;Culture=9226&amp;UICulture=9226&amp;ReportStack=1&amp;OpType=ReportArea&amp;Controller=ClientControllerctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewerListas&amp;PageNumber=1&amp;ZoomMode=Percent&amp;ZoomPct=100&amp;ReloadDocMap=true&amp;SearchStartPage=0&amp;LinkTarget=_top" id="report" name="report" frameborder="0" noresize="true" onload="parent.ClientControllerctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewerListas.OnReportFrameLoaded();" />
        </frameset>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot

best

Guillaume

Comment: Update the question heading with what exactly you are looking for? As currently written `Displaying Javascript #document in Selenium` it is hard to understand what you are asking for. Also update the _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_

Comment: Thank you, I found my way finally  !

Comment: If you have found the answer on your own it is better to add the answer as an **Answer** for this question for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was just to mimick the API request that is generated by the javascript recovering the report id and the control ID in the javascript tag inside the src element:

```
url="view-source:http://gestion.cnsc.gov.co/WebSetupDocentes/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?Mode=true&ReportID="+report+"&ControlID="+control+"&Culture=9226&UICulture=9226&ReportStack=1&OpType=ReportArea&Controller=ClientControllerctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewerListas&PageNumber=1&ZoomMode=Percent&ZoomPct=100&ReloadDocMap=true&SearchStartPage=0&LinkTarget=_top"
driver.get(url)
```